# 2 Kernels after upgrade to 20.04. One boots (with issues), other doesn't at all

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, kernel, 20.04

Machine:
MSI GS65 (nvidia rtx 2060)
Dual Boot (with Windows 10)

After upgrade to 20.04 LTS from 18.04 LTS via commandline, I ended up with 2 kernels on the "Ubuntu advanced option" screen. The kernels are:

```
ii  linux-image-5.3.0-59-generic               5.3.0-59.53~18.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-37-generic               5.4.0-37.41                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
```

When I select `linux-image-5.4.0-37-generic`, PC doesn't boot into Ubuntu *at all*. When I edit during the grub menu and add `nomodeset` it says "kernel panic". If I don't, it doesn't boot into Ubuntu, rather, only shows blank screen with just MSI logo, nothing else.

When I select `linux-image-5.3.0-59-generic`, it boots into Ubuntu alright. Only issue is, my external monitor is not detected *at all*

[image]

Will appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I read in one of the threads to re-install the kernel.

I did `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-5.4.0-37-generic`, rebooted, and worked, including the extra monitor working.